# Struts2-Jquery Grid : Data not getting displayed

Tags: jquery, struts2

I'm using struts2-jquery grid.

gridmodel in my action class is getting updated correctly. But, nothing is getting displayed on the grid.

**struts.xml**

```
<struts>

    <package name="default" namespace="/searchAndUpdate" extends="struts-default,json-default">

        <action name="listUsers" class="com.pilot.web.action.ListUsers" method="getJSON">
            <result name="success">/jsp/userList.jsp</result>
            <result name="input">/jsp/userList.jsp</result>
        </action>
</package>
```

**userList.jsp**

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts-jquery-tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="sjg" uri="/struts-jquery-grid-tags"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head>
<sj:head jqueryui="true" jquerytheme="redmond"/>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<h3>Application Users</h3>
<s:actionerror/>
<s:actionmessage/>
<s:url id="remoteurl" action="/searchAndUpdate/listUsers"/>
    <sjg:grid
        id="gridtable" 
        caption="Application Users" 
        dataType="json" 
        href="%{remoteurl}" 
        pager="true" 
        gridModel="gridModel" 
        rowList="10,15,20" 
        rowNum="15" 
        rownumbers="true" 
        resizable="true" 
        viewrecords="true" 
    >
        <sjg:gridColumn name="id" index="id" title="Id" formatter="integer" sortable="false"/>
        <sjg:gridColumn name="userName" index="userName" title="User Name" sortable="true"/>
        <sjg:gridColumn name="fullName" index="fullName" title="Full Name" sortable="false"/>
        <sjg:gridColumn name="email" index="email" title="EMail" sortable="false"/>
    </sjg:grid>
</body>
</html>
```

**ListUsers.java**

```
package com.pilot.web.action;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
import com.oxxo.pilot.backend.jdbc.dao.impl.User;


public class ListUsers extends ActionSupport {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private List<User> gridModel;
        //get how many rows we want to have into the grid - rowNum attribute in the grid
        private Integer rows = 0;
        //Get the requested page. By default grid sets this to 1.
        private Integer page = 0;
        // Your Total Pages
        private Integer total = 0;
        // All Records
        private Integer records = 0;
        // sorting order - asc or desc
        private String sord;
        // get index row - i.e. user click to sort.
        private String sidx;
        public String getAllApplicationData() {
                List<User> users = userListFromDb();
                if (users != null && getSord() != null
                                && getSord().equalsIgnoreCase("asc")) {
                        Collections.sort(users, null);
                }
                if (getSord() != null && "desc".equalsIgnoreCase(getSord())) {
                        Collections.sort(users, null);
                        Collections.reverse(users);
                }
                setRecord(users.size());
                int to = (getRows() * getPage());
                if (to > getRecord())
                        to = getRecord();

                setGridModel(users);
                setTotal((int) Math.ceil((double) getRecord() / (double) getRows()));
                System.out.println("Total is : " + getTotal());
                System.out.println("Record is : " + getRecord());
                for(User user: users){
                        System.out.println(user.getUserName() + ", " + user.getFullName() + ", " + user.getEmail());
                }
                if (hasActionMessages() || hasActionErrors()) {
                        return INPUT;
                }
                return SUCCESS;
        }

        private List<User> userListFromDb() {
           // MOCKED List for now
                List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();
                User user1 = new User();
                user1.setId(1);
                user1.setUserName("user1");
                user1.setFullName("User ABC");
                user1.setEmail("user1@email.com");

                User user2 = new User();
                user2.setId(1);
                user2.setUserName("user2");
                user2.setFullName("User DEF");
                user2.setEmail("user2@email.com");

                users.add(user1);
                users.add(user2);
                return users; // TODO FETCH LIST OF USERS FROM DB
        }

        public String getJSON() {
                System.out.println("here in getJSON");
                return getAllApplicationData();
        }

        public Integer getRows() {
                return rows;
        }

        public void setRows(Integer rows) {
                this.rows = rows;
        }

        public Integer getPage() {
                return page;
        }

        public void setPage(Integer page) {
                this.page = page;
        }

        public Integer getTotal() {
                return total;
        }

        public void setTotal(Integer total) {
                this.total = total;
        }

        public Integer getRecord() {
                return records;
        }

        public void setRecord(Integer records) {
                this.records = records;
                if (this.records > 0 && this.rows > 0) {
                        this.total = (int) Math.ceil((double) this.records
                                        / (double) this.rows);
                } else {
                        this.total = 0;
                }
        }
        public List<User> getGridModel() {
                return gridModel;
        }
        public void setGridModel(List<User> gridModel) {
                this.gridModel = gridModel;
        }
        public String getSord() {
                return sord;
        }
        public void setSord(String sord) {
                this.sord = sord;
        }
        public String getSidx() {
                return sidx;
        }
        public void setSidx(String sidx) {
                this.sidx = sidx;
        }
        public void setSearchField(String searchField) {
        }

        public void setSearchString(String searchString) {
        }

        public void setSearchOper(String searchOper) {
        }

        public void setLoadonce(boolean loadonce) {
        }
        public void setSession(Map<String, Object> session) {
        }
}
```

I did refer to the solution on [struts2 jquery grid data not load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6411589/struts2-jquery-grid-data-not-load?answertab=active#tab-top)

But that solution did not work. Instead of data getting displayed on the grid, it prompted to save the file & that file contained the following info:

> {"JSON":"success","gridModel":[{"email":"user1@email.com","fullName":"User ABC","id":1,"userName":"user1"},{"email":"user2@email.com","fullName":"User DEF","id":1,"userName":"user2"}],"page":0,"record":2,"rows":0,"sidx":null,"sord":null,"total":2147483647}*

As per my understanding row & page are automatically handled by the plugin. But as per the json data above they are not getting incremented. Hard-coded them to the size of the gridmodel and the json data I got is:

> *{"JSON":"success","allApplicationData":"success","gridModel":[{"email":"user1@email.com","fullName":"User ABC","id":1,"userName":"user1"},{"email":"user2@email.com","fullName":"User DEF","id":1,"userName":"user2"}],"page":1,"record":2,"rows":2,"sidx":null,"sord":null,"total":1}*

On updating  struts.xml as

```
 <result-types>
        <result-type name="json" class="org.apache.struts2.json.JSONResult" />
        </result-types>
        <action name="listUsers" class="com.oxxo.pilot.web.action.ListUsers">
            <result name="success" type="json">/jsp/userList.jsp</result>
            <result name="input" type="json">/jsp/userList.jsp</result>
        </action>
```

the json data is displayed on the browser.

Thanks,
Shikha

Comment: Do you have any plugin that automatically downloads specific data format on your browser? Did you try on different browsers?

Comment: No, I'm not using any such plugin. I tried on IE & Chrome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct solution is :

**Struts.xml:**

```
<result-types>
            <result-type name="json" class="org.apache.struts2.json.JSONResult" />
        </result-types>

<action name="listUsers" method="getAllApplicationData"   class="com.pilot.web.action.ListUsers">
            <result name="success">/jsp/userList.jsp</result>
            <result name="input">/jsp/fail.jsp</result>
        </action>
        <action name="getData" method="getAllApplicationData"   class="com.pilot.web.action.ListUsers">
            <result name="success" type="json"></result>
        </action>
```

**Index.jsp**

```
<s:form action="/searchAndUpdate/listUsers" method="post">
        <s:submit name="ListUsers" value="List All Users" align="right" />
    </s:form>
```

**userList.jsp**

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts-jquery-tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="sjg" uri="/struts-jquery-grid-tags"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head>
<sj:head jqueryui="true" jquerytheme="redmond"/>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<h3>Application Users</h3>
<s:actionerror/>
<s:actionmessage/>
<s:url id="remoteurl" action="/searchAndUpdate/getData"/>
    <sjg:grid
        id="gridtable" 
        caption="Application Users" 
        href="%{remoteurl}" 
        pager="true" 
        gridModel="gridModel" 
        rowList="10,15,20" 
        rowNum="15" 
        rownumbers="true" 
        resizable="true" 
        viewrecords="true" 
        name="gridModel" 
    >
        <sjg:gridColumn name="id" index="id" title="Id" formatter="integer" sortable="false"/>
        <sjg:gridColumn name="userName" index="userName" title="User Name" sortable="true"/>
        <sjg:gridColumn name="fullName" index="fullName" title="Full Name" sortable="false"/>
        <sjg:gridColumn name="email" index="email" title="EMail" sortable="false"/>
    </sjg:grid>
</body>
</html>
```

This is a working code. Working perfectly fine :)

The issue was : 
The jsp accepts data type json as an input & the action ListUsers has to render a jsp. So, I made two different actions. One that returns "json" which serves as an input to the jsp & one which renders the jsp on success.

Answer (score 0):

action should return JSON.

```
 <action name="listUsers" class="com.pilot.web.action.ListUsers" method="getJSON">
            <result name="success" type="json"/>
        </action>
```

[You can find a few grid examples here.](http://www.onlinexamples.com/searchactionfull.action?keywords=grid&idlabels=21)

Comment: I did try that as I wrote. But it displays the json data on the browser & not the grid. Might be I'm missing something else too which I'm not able to figure out.

Comment: You tried this : `<result name="success" type="json">/jsp/userList.jsp</result>`
and I am saying this : `<result name="success" type="json"/>`. Moreover, have you tried some other examples.

Comment: Yes, I tired this too. But it didn't solve the problem. I did check the link you gave, but couldn't figure out what's wrong/missing in my code.

Comment: all I can now say is that may be the versions of plugin and struts2 are not matching. Try using struts2.2.3 and plugin version 3.2.1

Answer (score 0):

Try to have 2 methods that return parameters in your action class. If the result name is INPUT you should return normal parameters. And when you query your grid values you should return JSON. What am I saying is change your action results to this:

```
<action name="listUsers_*" method={1} class="com.oxxo.pilot.web.action.ListUsers">
    <result name="success" type="json">/jsp/userList.jsp</result>
    <result name="input">/jsp/userList.jsp</result>
</action>
```

And in your action class

```
public String execute() throws Exception { return INPUT;}
public String getJSON() { return getAllApplicationData();}
```

I don't know if execute() method normally  returns INPUT when it is not implemented

In your page, add `getJSON` to call getJSON method on your action class.

```
<s:url id="remoteurl" action="listUsers_getJSON"/>
```

Hope this helps, and let me know if you worked it out

Comment: well in Action Support class it is defined to return only `SUCCESS`

Comment: You mean, in case it is not overridden?

Comment: I guess, the plugin you're using is sending wrong MIME type to the browser. Which version of struts-jqgrid, struts-jquery plugins are you using? Do you have extra javascripts that is related to your grid?

Comment: Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2590335/ajaxfileupload-return-download-panel-when-data-is-json

Comment: I am using 3.2.1 version of both. No, I'm not using any javascripts.

Comment: What is your Struts and struts2-json-plugin versions? If you're using compatible version, then I have no clue what is wrong with it. Everything looks fine